# Cross-referencing enumerate item

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, labels

I need to cross-reference the item in enumerate. Here is what I have.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Solve $x^2=1$.
    \item Solve $x^2=4$.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{enum:1} Find all roots.
        \item For each root in (\ref{enum:1}), subtract 2 from it.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It works fine but I want to have (a) instead of (2a) in the last line. In other words, I only want to have the label within the current enumerate. Thanks.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Why did you delete your answer?  It gives valuable information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a different solution using the `enumitem` package. With it we can configure how references to items look. In this MWE I change the reference format of second level `enumerate` globally.

As an added bonus we do not have to mess with internals.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
  ref=(\alph*),
}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Solve $x^2=1$.
    \item Solve $x^2=4$.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{enum:1} Find all roots.
        \item For each root in \ref{enum:1}, subtract 2 from it.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The key is to redefine the macro `\p@enumii`, which holds the prefix used in this situation:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Solve $x^2=1$.
    \item Solve $x^2=4$.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \makeatletter
        \renewcommand*\p@enumii{}
        \makeatother
        \item \label{enum:1} Find all roots.
        \item For each root in (\ref{enum:1}), subtract 2 from it.
    \end{enumerate}
    \item To show that the redefinition is local:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{enum:2} Find all roots.
        \item For each root in (\ref{enum:2}), subtract 2 from it.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: or just use `enumitem` to split them apart. I never even realized that barebones `enumerate` behaved like that on inner lists.

Comment: @daleif: Please, do post an answer with your solution, which is surely better than mine.

Comment: @GuM :-):-). I have upvoted all :-(